# Microsoft Access 2007 / 2012 Source Control using Team Foundation Services (2012)

Tags: tfs, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I've been struggling for few days on this workaround...

So, as you may know, Microsoft ran its cloud ALM platform : team foundation services (https://tfs.visualstudio.com/). It is free to use for teams containing less that 5 users... and it can be used with MS Access !

In the same time a customer of mine asked me to maintain a bundle of internally developed MS Access applications :(.

Though we may progressively migrate thees application to .Net, the first step will be to debug and maintain access applications... So to minimize issues I decided to put it under source management, and why not ALM.

The problem is Access files (mdb :() are binary files.

There are no explicit explanations to get it work with Team Foundation Services.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Great exactly what I searched

Comment: For a step by step article with video in how to do this check out: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/long-overdue-article-source-control-tfs-microsoft-access-griggs?trk=prof-post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have the solution!

1. Install Team Explorer 2012

   This software is provided by Microsoft to Access to TFS 2012 and is free to use with your TFS licence:  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30656
2. Install Team Foundation Server MSSCCI Provider 2012

   This is used by the source control plugin for MS Access.
   http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b5b5053e-af34-4fa3-9098-aaa3f3f007cd
3. Download the MS Access developer extensions for Access 2007

   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24569

   Or, for Access 2010

   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6840
4. Add the server : https://xxxxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/

That's all.

Comment: Some people prefer http://servername/DefaultCollection instead of http://xxxxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection